# ReinforcedTypings RtDictionaryType substitution

Tags: reinforced-typings

I try to use Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.FSharpMap (standrad Map in F#) in my model.
It implements

```
System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue>
```

and

```
System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyCollection<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>
```

so it is a Dictionary type.
Unfortunately ReinforcedTypings gives me this warning:

> Type resolvation warning RT0003: Could not find suitable TypeScript
> type for System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[[System.String,
> System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[BkkFutar.Data.BKKApi.RouteReference,
> BkkFutarCore.Data, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=null]]. 'any' assumed

It looks like it identifies as an IReadOnlyCollection<KeyValuePair<K, V>> and not as a dictionary.

I also tried to use

```
Substitute(typeof(FSharpMap<,>),` new RtDictionaryType())
```

in the configuration but it does not work.
On the other hand

```
Substitute(typeof(FSharpMap<string,string>), new RtDictionaryType(new RtSimpleTypeName("string"), new RtSimpleTypeName("string")))
```

does work but I dont want nor can specify every case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `SubstituteGeneric` instead:

```cs
SubstituteGeneric(typeof(FSharpMap<,>), (t, tr) =>
{
    var args = t.GetGenericArguments();
    return new RtDictionaryType(tr.ResolveTypeName(args[0]),tr.ResolveTypeName(args[1]));
})
```

I've made corresponding [unit test](https://github.com/reinforced/Reinforced.Typings/blob/master/Reinforced.Typings.Tests/SpecificCases/SpecificTestCases.ADIXReadonlyDictionaryWorkaround.cs) especially for you. :)

It seems to be internal RT's... inconvenience, not a bug per se. RT detects dictionaries by implemented `IDictionary<,>` interface first and then, if not succeded, it tries to find `IEnumerable`s in type. That is why you've got warning about `KeyValuePair<,>`: `FSharpMap` implements `IEnumerable<>` of them.

The `IDictionary<,>` interface represents actually mutable hashmap that contains `Add` method. `IReadOnlyDictionary` appeared in .NET a bit later than early versions of RT were made.

By the way it is not correct to resolve `IReadOnlyDictionary` to TypeScript's hash object because this one actually IS mutable. But anyway I will consider this improvement for next versions of RT.

Comment: Thank you! I was focusing too much on Substitute, I haven't even noticed  SubstituteGeneric...

By the way in the ```IsDictionary``` method there is a

```if (typeof(IReadOnlyDictionary<,>)._IsAssignableFrom(tg)) return true;```

part, so it should match, shouldn't it?

I know the TS object is not immutable but I wanted to reach this point first. Actually I only read these object so I may just leave them this way...